# Connection timeout when trying to open a connection

Tags: ado.net

I'm getting this error:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I know that most of the time this problem is fixed by adding the commandtimeout property of a sqlcommand.

The problem is that I'm getting this error trying to do this:

Dim con as new SqlConnection("connstring")

con.open() ' bang!, i'm getting the error here.

The strange thing is that i'm getting the error when trying to open the connection, and the problem is intermitent, i mean I'm not getting this error always.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?, or what can be causing the error?

Comment: The most common error is you've simply passed in a wrong connection string :-)
Other possibilities,the server is very very busy, and have trouble accepting new connections. The server isn't setup properly to accept connections from your client in the way you think it is set up.

Comment: If it was a bad constring the problem would happen every time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you've maxed out connections to it?  Are you closing all the connections you're opening?

Comment: yes, whe are using a common DAL library handling the connection closing.

Comment: Are you opening connections in a loop somewhere causing very many to be open at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Event logs on both boxes (Assuming you are running seperate)? I would double check what connections are open even if i was using a DAL using sp_who2 or similar.

Otherwise maybe a dodgy network which wont be so easy to debug, you should see signs in the event logs of this.

Does increasing the connection timeout help? This is not a solution but may help you debug.